# J2ME High Secured app for m-commerce

Tags: security, java-me, wap

I am creating a j2me application for mcommerce, which uses mobile internet(gprs). I wanted make it more secured by binding the application to the SIM card and the device. That is a user should be able to login to the system, only using his/her SIM card or from the registered mobile number.

To achieve this I need to fetch the mobile number.
So, on login i thought of Triggering an SMS from the server with a key, which the application reads and uses the key for the entire session. Here the challenge is, that sms should not go to the inbox. 
Any suggestions pls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be achieved using [the Wireless Messaging API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205).  Have the MIDlet set up a server connection on a chosen port number, then send the SMS to that port number.  It will go straight to your app, bypassing the inbox.  If you use the [Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/), you can even make the SMS start your app if it is not running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, how do i sent the sms to the specified port. I am using an SMS gateway application, it does not have any option to set the UDH header of the sms.

Comment: I have yet to find the gateways which support this feature. You don't want customers to complain that they can't get in only because they are roaming (abroad or just on a different network in the same country) and the provider filters out the portnr

Comment: Is there any ways that i can bind my J2ME application with the phone and sim card. (that is the application should make requests only from his/her registered) number.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the user sees the number in his/her inbox.
As long as the key is only used that session, it is her/his responsibility to not share the key with others.

The one thing you make sure is that ONLY the person who owns the SMS phonenumber gets the key and is able to log on.

This doesn't take care of the phone being stolen though.

Comment: If the phone is being stolen it is the duty of the customer to call the telcom and deactivate the number. In that case mobile app will not work with any other number. There is also an additional password security. I want to make sure, the person logs in to the system only using his number.